# What is the difference in the manner of face wrappings?

Tags: greek, john, linguistics

In the gospel of John, there are two different descriptions of facial coverings on individuals that were buried.

Lazarus account

> "And he that was dead came forth, bound hand and foot with graveclothes: and his face was bound about with a napkin. Jesus saith unto them, Loose him, and let him go."–John 11:44 (KJV)

Jesus account

> "And the napkin, that was about his head, not lying with the linen clothes, but wrapped together in a place by itself."–John 20:7 (KJV)

What is the difference in usage and meaning of *perideo* [Strong 4019](https://biblehub.com/greek/4019.htm) in the Lazarus account and *entulisso* [Strong 1794](https://biblehub.com/greek/1794.htm) in the Jesus account?

Comment: I have edited only to link your two Strong references to Biblehub online. (Up-voted +1.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

περιεδέδετο , the verb used in John 11:44, is the pluperfect, indicative, middle or passive 3rd person singular ([Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/11-44.htm)) of the verb περιδεω 'to bind around'.

ἐντετυλιγμένον , the verb used in John 20:7, is the perfect participle, middle or passive, accusative neuter singular ([Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/20-7.htm)) of the verb ἐντυλίσσω 'to wrap up'.

There is nothing unusual in these verbs. They simply indicate the *condition* of that which was about Lazarus' head and that which had been about Jesus' head. One was, in the narrative, actually bound around, the other was, in the narrative, folded up.

John 11:44 states that what was around Lazarus' head was σουδαρίῳ a headcloth (dative neuter singular [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/11-44.htm)).

John 20:7 states that what was around Jesus' head was the same - σουδάριον (genitive neuter plural - [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/20-7.htm)).

Therefore there is no indication of any difference in material. The difference is in the condition of the cloth : bound around or folded up.

I cannot think of any further 'difference' (according to the OP) in usage or meaning that would be relevant to the text.

The spiritual meaning is quite clear, but that would be another question and a further answer.

Comment: Agreed.  Far from showing a difference, the two accounts actually show that the burial practice in the two cases was essentially identical.  BTW - these two texts forever dismiss the Shroud of Turin as a fraud as only one sheet was used; whereas, Jesus' and Lazarus' head wrapping was separate.

Comment: @Dottard Good point about Turin. I hadn't thought of that.